# Why can't I sed two [or more..] empty lines to one empty line?

Tags: sed

Why can't I sed two [or more..] empty lines to one empty line? What is the trick?

```
echo -e "hello\n\n\nhello2" | sed 's/^$\n^$/\n/g'
hello


hello2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason your `sed` failed is that unless you specify a multi-line operator, it operates on the stream one line at a time. Multiple beginning of line `^` and  end of line `$` operators are meaningless when strung together like that if you are only looking at the text one line at a time.

The easist way to collapse multiple blank lines is with `cat`. From the man page:

> -s, --squeeze-blank
>     suppress repeated empty output lines

It works like this:

```
$ echo -e "hello\n\n\nworld" | cat -s
hello

world
```

If you want to remove the blank lines entirely rather than compressing them, use `grep`:

```
$ echo -e "hello\n\n\nworld" | grep -v '^$'
hello
world
```

Note that if you really want to do this in `sed` you have to use complicated expressions and actions. Here is an example (thanks to [fred](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2343/fred)) that collapses any number of sequencial blanks into a single blank line:

```
$ echo -e "hello\n\n\nworld" | sed -re '$!N;/^\n$/!P;D'
hello

world
```

You can see why `cat -s` is a good deal easier if collapsing multiple blank lines is all you are after!

Comment: you're a real living god.

Comment: @LanceBaynes: Nope, just a man who's had the same question and read enough other people's code to notice the answers.

Comment: Here is [O'Reilly's Command Summary for sed](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/appa_03.htm)

Comment: `echo -e "hello\n\n\nworld\n\n"` no work.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `awk` for posterity which allows you to more control is something like:

```
cat file | awk 'BEGIN {sp=0} \
         {if (length($0)==1) {sp=sp+1} \
          if (sp>=1&&length($0)==1) {
          } else {
             for (i=1;i<=((3<sp)?3:sp);i++) {print ""}
             print $0; sp=0}
    }'
```

This compresses any number of lines of space (`length($0)==1`) into fewer, but not necessarily zero (3 in this case).

So 1, 2, or 3 lines of blank space will be preserved, but more than 3 will always be compressed to 3.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e '/./b' -e :n -e 'N;s/\n$//;tn' infile`